# How does the brain manifest and realize the intention to resist sleep?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology, sleep, neurotransmitter

The question title says it all. What happens in my brain when I resist sleep? I would appreciate explanations on neurotransmitter changes, what areas of the brain activate to resist sleep, what can an EEG tell us about that condition, are there any phases to that condition..

Switching to sleep mode is very complex and automatic process and it takes over and changes the functions of the whole brain (and the whole body also), so..

What actually does the brain **do** to not fall asleep?